# Fatal error: Call to undefined function quiz_type_access_load()

Tags: 7, routes

Getting the following error after switching servers. The setup is multisite on a linux box. The troublemaker is on subdomain. 
So far: 
disabled quiz and quiz submodules, 
cleared the cache, nothing really works.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function quiz_type_access_load() in /path/to/drupal/includes/menu.inc on line 411
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to find and delete records in "menu_links" and "menu_router" tables of your database which have "quiz_type_access_load" occurrences.

Be careful: backup the database first!